# Arduino Mega with SIM800L running Modbus TCP/IP

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm, tcpip, modbus

I'm trying to set up an Arduino Mega with a SIM800L module and trying to get Modbus TCP running on said Mega. I've set Modbus TCP over wifi and serial before but I used libraries for those. The problem is, I can't find a suitable library for SIM800L that has Modbus support in it. The project is supposed to get Modbus TCP to places without wifi, using a static IP enabled sim card. My question here is, am I missing something? While working with ESP8266 and Serial, I was able to find a ton of libraries to work with, but SIM800 series returns nothing for me.
Thanks!

Comment: In 99% of cases, problems with SIM800L came for voltage supply. With wrong voltage supply of without enough power, it doesn't work at all, or (worst case!!) it works for sending or receving 2 or 3 sets of data then start to loose data...

Comment: It's already working. Voltage supply isn't the problem. I suppose you didn't exactly read the question. My problem is that I can't find a library that supports Modbus and SIM800 module. Thanks for the tip anyways!

Comment: Well the problem for me is Modbus TCP libraries I have been using requires you to have a MAC ID or an IP adress in their implementation while I don't need any of those while using a SIM800 if I am correct. How am I going to get past that?